# second instance with same name and type as previously created instance attributes are not intialized

Tags: python, object

I have a class Household

```
class Household:
    def __init__(self,A=[]):

        self._A = A
    @property
    def A(self):
        """List of firms connected to by type A"""
        return self._A

    @A.setter
    def A(self, value):
        self._A = value
```

```
h = Household()
h.A.append(4)

h = Household()
h.A
```

I thought this should return empty list [].  But instead I get [4]. Why?

Comment: I mean obviously I am creating a name collision here, I didn't intend to do that

Comment: It's not a name collision, check the duplicate question for a thorough explanation.

Comment: Note, your `property` is completely pointless, don't use it it defeats the *entire point*. Just use a regular attribute

Comment: why is it pointless? I need this attribute to be a list

Comment: It's ok to publicly expose the attribute `A` in Python. You are most likely coming from a different language (such as Java) where getters and setters are the norm even if they do nothing (as in your example).

Comment: oh I see thanks ok im good thanks